# How to remove a Visual studio extension that gives a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error during removal or update?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

The 'Developer Analytics Tools' Visual Studio 2015 extension keeps giving me an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error when I try to remove it or update it. That's the error also in the installlog.

I tried vsixinstaller /q /a /u:1b11efe-37ad-45dd-a8f9-a540a6ed7bcb several times (no output messages) and when I launch VS, the extension is still there.  happened. The identifier is from the manifest file.

I tried [TotalUninstaller tool](https://totaluninstaller.codeplex.com/) and it's not listing the extension.

It seems the physical extension is not there but there are some remnants or something that makes VS think it's still there.

Anyone knows how to remove it cleanly? Registry entry or file in some folder that needs to be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions. You can find directories with random names. Go through each folder and find the file extension.vsixmanifest to find the extension name. Then delete the entire directory of the extension you want to remove.